# Update GUI with dependent tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, dependencies

I am developing a complex multithreaded application that has interactions with a user and multiple servers. I would like to display to the user the consistent state. Say when property A changes, then properties B, C, D become inconsistent and need to be updated - update may require some complex algorithm to run that depends on other properties. But the property E does not depend on A, so it does not need to get updated.

My problem is that any thread can change any property at any time, of course with the usage of synchronized. So when the thread finishes its task with the updated data acquired, this data may be already outdated. In the theoretical reasoning of my application, there is a possible consistent state when no other updated is required - and this I would like to display to the user.

How are these dependencies managed in general in GUI multithreaded applications? Currently, I am using a timestamp, but this is not sufficient to address more complex dependencies. I was thinking of using gradle or maven but it seems to be overkill and the GUI application should stay quick and responsive. I have a solution in my mind, however later it may require additional extensions and for this reason I would rather use some existing solution.

Comment: im not sure if i understood what u want but may be u are looking something like  the observer pattern, in swing-gui apps see `PropertyChangeListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Swing provides listeners so that you as the developer can know when an action happens, like pressing a button.

In the same manner, your threads can provide action listeners, so that the Swing GUI can know when to update a property.

You will have to write these action listeners.  An example is found in the Javadoc for [EventListenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html)

Read this article, [Event Listener](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=150), for another example of writing event listeners.

Comment: I was thinking of something more complex, but it seems that EventListeners should be sufficient for now. Thanks!